# Collision of photon with proton resulting in pi-meson and scattered proton

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics

I've been stuck on this question for quite some time now. I have a photon colliding with a stationary proton enabling the creation of a pion via $\gamma + p = p' + \pi^0$. The pion $\pi^0$ get's scattered away at an angle $\theta$ relative to the x-axis. After writing out the conservation of four momentum and squaring both sides you can find that

$$2h \nu m_p = 2 m_{\pi^0}m_pc^2\gamma(v_{rel}) + m_{\pi^0}^2c^2$$

from which you can then easily find the least amount of energy required to create the pion by setting the relative velocity to zero, my question now is how to derive the kinetic energy of the $\pi^0$-meson, $T_{\pi^0}$, in the 'lab enviroment' (i.e where the proton was initially at rest) in terms of the frequency of the photon, the rest masses and the angle $\theta$. I don't really need a full answer, just some leeway on how you should go about this,I know the kinetic energy can be written as: $$T_{\pi^0} = \gamma(v)m_{\pi^0}c^2 - m_{\pi^0}c^2$$ from which you could easily find the kinetic energy upond finding $\gamma$, but this isn't the same $\gamma$ as $\gamma(v_{rel})$... So I tried using the conservation of 3-momentum but then I find
$$\frac{h\nu}{c} = |\vec{p_{\pi^0}}|\cos(\theta) + |\vec{p_{p}}|\cos(\phi)$$ With $\phi$ bothering me as it shouldn't even be in the final answer, any help?

**Edit:**
For @Myridium the derivation of the first formula:
$$P^\mu_\gamma + P^\mu_p = P^\mu_{p'} + P^\mu_{\pi^0}$$
squaring both sides and projecting using $\eta_{\mu\mu}$:
$$0 + 2P^\mu_\gamma P_{\mu}^{(p)} = m_{\pi^0}^2c^2 + 2P^\mu_{p'}P_{\mu}^{(\pi^0)}$$
Now solving the left in the proton rest frame (i.e the lab frame) and solving the right in the pion rest frame giving rise to a $P^0$ for the scattered proton perceived by the pion of $m_pc\gamma(v_{rel})$:
$$2\frac{h\nu}{c}m_pc = 2m_{\pi^0}cm_pc\gamma(v_{rel}) + m_{\pi^0}^2c^2$$
My little adventure in three-momentum conservation was basically just stating that:
$$\vec{P_\gamma} = \vec{P_p'} + \vec{P_{\pi^0}}$$
And as the photon only has an x-component, projecting the right side to the x-axis (with $\phi$ being an angle I made up as the scattered proton angle to the x-axis). I guess you could project everything to the y-axis as well and get an equation of the form
$$0 = |\vec{p_{\pi^0}}|\sin(\theta) + |\vec{p_{p}}|\sin(\phi)$$
but I have no clue how this would help.

Comment: Can you write out the equations for conservation of 4-momentum, and how you derived the expression with $\phi$ in it?

Comment: The smart way to work on particle scatterings is to use their energy -momentum  fourvectors http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html.

Comment: @annav this I know, and I used it to arrive at the first formula, I just have no clue how I could use it to end at an answer for the second question

Comment: http://www.phys.ufl.edu/~avery/course/4390/f2015/lectures/relativistic_kinematics_1.pdf